# how to replace '[[' with '${' in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to replace `[[` with `${`.

```
var str = "it is [[test example [[testing";
var res = str.replace(/[[[]/g, "${");
```

I am getting the result `"it is ${${test example ${${testing"` but I want the result `"it is ${test example ${testing"`.

Comment: Why the downvote? The question is ok, there's a clear explanation of the problem and a sample code of what's been tried..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect.

```
[[[]
```

will match **one or two** `[` and replace one `[` by `${`.

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gZ1lR3/1) of incorrect regular expression.

`[` is special symbol in Regular Expression. So, to match literal `[`, 
you need to escape `[` in `regex` by preceding it `\`. Without it `[` is treated as character class.

```js
var str = "it is [[test example [[testing";
var res = str.replace(/\[\[/g, "${");
//                     ^^^^

document.write(res);
```

Comment: Well, I think there is one thing everyone here are forgetting. I will upvote this answer if you find this issue in your snippet.

Answer (score 4):

you want to escape the [ using \

```
var res = str.replace(/\[\[/g, "${");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just problem with escape characters.
use `\` before `[`.

```
var str = "it is [[test example [[testing";
var res = str.replace(/\[\[/g, "${");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `regex`

```
var res = str.split('[[').join('${');
```

**Sample Here:**

```js
var str = "it is [[test example [[testing";
var res = str.split('[[').join('${');

document.write(res);
```